# What is the work around for XAML validation not updating the CLR property if validation fails

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

My xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
 <TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
       <Binding Path="ContactNumber"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                   <Binding.ValidationRules>
                       <validators:ContactValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = "True"  />
                   </Binding.ValidationRules>
       </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
 <Button Command="{Binding SaveContact}"/>
```

My View Model(Already implements Inotify Fody Weaver, Standard Relay Command Implementation for ICommand)

```
 public class DemoVM{
public string ContactNumber{get;set;}
public ICommand SaveContact=new RelayCommand(()=> //Simulate Db save of (ContactNumber));

}
```

My validation class

```
  public class ContactValidation : ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
if (//some regex match)
 return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
else
 return new ValidationResult(false,"Error message")
  }
}
```

Everytime the validation rule returns a valid result, the ContactNumber Property is updated. When the validation rule returns invalid result, the ContactNumber property is its last validated value.
How do i proceed to validate all the values in the xaml(Show error message and such) side of code as well as in my viewmodel(Prevent submit if error showing or enable button only if all fields validated)?

The official databinding document by MSDN covers bothe validation part separately bu there is nothing if we want to make use of the same Validation Rules to validate from both UI and code behind perspective.

Comment: ValidationRules put validation in the realm of the view, and the viewmodel is "unaware" of it. If you want to get the viewmodel involved, implement [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on the viewmodel instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the `ValidationRules` in the view and implement the validation logic in your view model.

This is done by implementing the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. Validate your data in the setter of your properies as suggested in the following TechNet article.

**WPF 4.5: Validating Data in Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

This is the MVVM way of implementing data validation. Using a `ValidationRule` is not.